# How to make Checkbox active macro that types text at the selection point when checked?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA, and I've spent the last four hours trying to figure this out and I'm totally lost.

I'm trying to make this checkbox, written as such:

```
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Married "
    Selection.FormFields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormCheckBox
    Set Married = ActiveDocument.FormFields(3)
    For Each Married In ActiveDocument.FormFields
        Married.CalculateOnExit = True
    Next Married
```

when checked, do:

```
        Selection.TypeText Text:=", spouse of the grantor, releases all rights in the premises conveyed."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak
```

I've tried doing things such as:

```
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("Check1").Checkbox.Value = True Then
        Selection.TypeText Text:=", spouse of the grantor, releases all rights in the premises conveyed."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak
```

But that doesn't work. I've also tried defining subs and calling them and that hasn't worked. I'm not sure what to do, I feel like this task should be relatively simple.

Comment: In your first example, the macro will only run if the document is protected, but you can insert a new formfield without first unprotecting the document. The second example could work, but that text will have to go into an unprotected area of the document, or you'll have to unprotect the document, or you'll have to have a text formfield where the text can be entered.

Comment: You need to start by defining the place in the document where the text is to appear. You could do this by designing the forma with a formfield in the correct position, Or you could use a bookmark. There are many methods. Then, once you have a place in the document to refer to, entering text there is easy.

Comment: John, thanks for replying. The unprotect method got the text to be created. However, the text is created regardless of the checkbox value being true or not. Why may this be?

Comment: I can't tell, you've only posted code fragments. Please edit your post with a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example